# Linear space of functionals from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Show that linear space of functionals from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ i.e. $L(\mathbb R^n; \mathbb R)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

All I know is that I have to find bijection between these two, but what will be the form of it? Since one set contains functionals which transform vectors from $\mathbb R^n$ and the other is just the set of vectors.

Any hints?

Comment: Take $(i(x))(t) = \langle x, t \rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Pick a basis $\;\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$, and define for each $\;j=1,2,...,n\;$ a linear functional :

$$f_jv_k:=\delta_{jk}\;,\;\;\text{with the Kronecker delta}\;\;\delta_{jk}:=\begin{cases}1,&j=k\\0,&j\neq k\end{cases}$$

and extend each $\;f_j\,'$ s definition by linearity.

Comment: I will stick to your answer because we haven't got dot product properly defined yet. What do you mean by extending it? I am a little bit confused. Each of these $f_j$'s is an element of $L(\mathbb R^n; \mathbb R)$ but I cannot see how these $f_j$'s are combined to make transformation between two spaces from my problem. Could you explain it?

Comment: @janusz To define a linear transformation it is enough to define the images of the elements in a specific basis. Since every element in the space can be written as a linear combination of the elements from the basis (and in a unique way) you can easily extend your function to a linear transformation on the whole space.

Comment: @Mark Ok I understand it. Just a question about its form. Is it possible to write down concise expression?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by concise expression. You want to see how the extension looks like?

Comment: @Mark I mean, what I was thinking is that for a given functional from one space match one and only vector from $\mathbb R^n$. But I don't think it is rather possible. And yes, what the extension looks like?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, you can prove that the functionals $f_1,...f_n$ that DonAntonio defined in his answer are a basis of $L(\mathbb{R^n};\mathbb{R})$. Then the correspondence is easy to guess: $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_jf_j\to\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_jv_j$. Obviously you have some work to do here.

Comment: As for the extension of a function to a linear transformation...Well, if you know what are $T(v_1),...,T(v_n)$ then you just define $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_jv_j=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_jT(v_j)$. Since this is a linear tranformation it can't be defined in a different way.

Comment: @Mark Excellent explanations, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not just a bijection. It has to be a bijective linear transformation. Define $\phi:\mathbb{R^n}\to L(\mathbb{R^n};\mathbb{R})$ by $\phi(v)=\psi_v$ where $\psi_v(x)=\langle x,v\rangle$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\langle\rangle$ is the standard dot product. I'll leave it to you to check why $\phi$ is a linear transformation and a bijection.